# Attempt to connect to socket in redux-saga when error occurs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, websocket, redux-saga

I prepared saga using channels as follows:

```
function* createEventChannel(socket, dataItem) {
  const stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
  const token = yield select(makeSelectToken);
  return eventChannel(emit => {
    stompClient.connect(
      getAuthorization(token),
      frame => {
        stompClient.subscribe('/queue/data', message => {
          const response = JSON.parse(message.body);
          emit(response);
        });
        stompClient.subscribe('/queue/error', message => {
          const error = JSON.parse(message.body);
          emit(error);
        });
        stompClient.send(
          '/register',
          {},
          JSON.stringify({
            request: {
              type: dataItem,
            },
          })
        );
      },
      error => emit({ error: 'Lost connection' })
    );
    return () => {
      socket.close();
      console.log('return close: ');
    };
  });
}

export function* initializeChannel(
  actionNames,
  requestParam
) {
  const mySocket = new SockJS('/ws');
  const channel = yield call(createEventChannel, mySocket, requestParam);
  while (true) {
    const { unmount, response } = yield race({
      unmount: take(UNMNOUT),
      response: take(channel),
    });
    if (unmount) {
      channel.close();
    } else {
      if (response) {
        yield put({
          type: FETCH_SUCCESS,
          payload: response.data,
        });
      }
      if (response.error) {
        yield put({
          type: actionNames.FETCH_ERROR,
          payload: response.error,
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I know it's quite a long piece of code but that's what I managed to prepare. Now I am facing three issues:

- when an error occurs, for example "connection loss" I would like to
  try to reconnect saga for example every 30 seconds. How this could be
  done?
- In the part with `stompClient.send` I register a dataItem to a queue. Now each time I am creating socket again. How I could make it in a way, I could register dataItem one after another that just join the existing queue and socket?
- when the socket is online, it doesn't react to internet loss, I searched many opened issues about it and I still don't know - is there a way to check the connection during work of websocket?